# No image in Exported Report to MS Word and Excel File

Tags: php, export, report, reporting, export-to-excel

I am working on the reporting part of my project, the project contain hundreds of dynamic generated reports and each report contain images and formatted followed by Table. And all these reports need to be downloadable in doc/docx (Ms Word), xls /xlsx(MS Excel) and PDF

For this I want to Convert the Generated HTML report to the corresponding file 
for this I am using following code

```
function export_attendance_view_doc($htmlcontent){
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=attendance_report.doc");
    echo $htmlcontent;
}   

function export_attendance_view_xls($htmlcontent){
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attendance_report.xls");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=attendance_report.doc");
    echo $htmlcontent;
}
```

Using the above code I am getting the doc and xls file but the issue is that the image is not rendering in the file if the script is run in live server working fine in localhost if I am using full url in `<img src` not displaying image in local if using relative path. Same in the case of Excel file.

[image: Image missing screenshot of downloaded file]

Comment: Check that the "full url" of your images are not linking to images in your computer. They should be available in the server that generates the files. But then, without knowing which library you use to generate the excel and doc files, it's difficult to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Alberto I am not using any library just using the above code. Image is available but I want to make the word file to work without Internet too